# Нужна ли запятая перед словом "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

Берегите русский язык как святыню.

Comment: После слова “как”? За что?

Answer (score 3):

Не нужна, нет сравнения. Здесь значение "в качестве" *(подобно святыне)*.

> *Берегите чистоту языка как святыню! Никогда не употребляйте иностранных слов. Русский язык так богат и гибок, что нам нечего брать
>   у тех, кто беднее нас.* (Тургенев)

[Правило:](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Nop0WzCpvtEC&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F:%201)%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20...%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%8E).&source=bl&ots=jpYqfbzX_R&sig=eIC0tzqDv7TOLezqIqSHSbsz_dI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-5vq50cnPAhVCCpoKHWg6AyUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%3A%201)%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20...%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%8E).&f=false)

> Запятая не ставится... если сравнительный оборот или все сочетание с
>   ним имеет характер устойчивого сочетания, например: ***беречь как
>   зеницу ока (как святыню)***; бросился как безумный; глуп как пробка;
>   пошел ко дну как камень.